# Page is not outputting correct data associated with an id

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am designing a forum. The pages I am going to mention are discussions.php and forum_view_category.php

discussions is the page that shows the different categories.

forum_view_categories is the page that displays the topics inside of that category.

As of now I am only testing this out and only have two categories. They have an id of 1 and 2. Whenever I click the link to go to the forum_view_category page, the correct link is being displayed with the appropriate id for the one I clicked.

My issue is that the posts from category 1 are showing in category 1 and 2. I do not have any topics in category 2, so my else statements should echo.

My discussions page has this link to get to the appropriate forum_view_category page..

```
$categories = "<a href='forum_view_category.php?cid=".$categoryid."'>" . $categoryTitle . "</a>";
```

Then this is the forum_view_category page.

```
$cid = $_GET['cid'];
$userid = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );

if(isset( $_SESSION['user'])) {
    $logged = " | <a href='forum_create_topic.php?cid=".$cid."'>Create a new topic</a>";
}
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM forum_categories WHERE id='".$cid."' LIMIT 1");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($numrows == 1){
    //$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM forum_topics WHERE `category_id` ='".$cid."' ORDER BY topic_reply_date DESC")
    $query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT t.*, COUNT(p.topic_id) AS tid2 
FROM forum_topics AS t JOIN forum_posts AS p on t.id = p.topic_id 
GROUP BY t.id DESC")
    or die ("Query2 failed: %s\n".($query2->error));
    $numrows2 = mysqli_num_rows($query2);
    //if ( false===$query2 ) {
        // die(' Query2 failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($query2->error));
    //}
    if($numrows2 > 0){
        $topics .= "<table width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>";
        //Change link once discussion page is made
        $topics .= "<tr><td colspan='3'><a href='discussions.php'>Return to Discussion Index</a>".$logged."<hr /></td></tr>";
        $topics .= "<tr style='background-color: #dddddd;'><td>Topic Title</td><td width='65' align='center'>Replies</td><td width='65' 
        align='center'>Views</td></tr>";
        $topics .= "<tr><td colspan='3'><hr /></td></tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){
            $tid = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['topic_title'];
            $views = $row['topic_views'];
            $replies = $row['tid2'];
            $date = $row['topic_date'];
            $date = fixDate($date);
            $creator = $row['topic_creator'];
            $topics .= "<tr><td><a href='forum_view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid."'>".$title."</a><br /><span class='post_info'>Posted 
            by: ". $creator. " " . $date."</span></td><td align='center'>".$replies."</td><td align='center'>".$views."</td></tr>";
            $topics .= "<tr><td colspan='3'><hr /></td></tr>";
        }
        $topics .="</table>";
        echo $topics;
    } else {
        echo "<a href='discussions.php'>Return to Discussions page</a><hr />";
        echo "<p>There are no topics in this category yet. ".$logged." </p>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<a href='discussions.php'>Return to Discussions page</a><hr />";
    echo "<p>You are trying to view a category that does not exist yet.</p>";
}
```

I changed some of the queries to JOIN's so that I could get other info throughout the site, I'm not sure if I did something wrong in them or what. So, I'm not sure why it is grabbing the correct id, but not displaying what is actually in it. Does anyone have any idea?

I believe it has to do specifically with this query...

```
//$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM forum_topics WHERE `category_id` ='".$cid."' ORDER BY topic_reply_date DESC")
$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT t.*, COUNT(p.topic_id) AS tid2
```

FROM forum_topics AS t JOIN forum_posts AS p on t.id = p.topic_id 
GROUP BY t.id DESC")

The commented out query was my old one. How can I join the old query with my new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put this-

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT t.*, COUNT(p.topic_id) AS tid2 FROM forum_topics AS t JOIN forum_posts AS p on t.id = p.topic_id WHERE t.category_id = ".$cid." GROUP BY t.id DESC")
or die ("Query2 failed: %s\n".($query2->error));
```

At the end of your query2

Comment: That makes my query fail.

Comment: Can you post updated query after addin this where clause to see wht could be wrong...

Comment: I tried here...`$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT t.*, COUNT(p.topic_id) AS tid2 
FROM forum_topics AS t JOIN forum_posts AS p on t.id = p.topic_id 
GROUP BY t.id DESC WHERE `category_id` ='".$cid."'")` and here`$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT t.*, COUNT(p.topic_id) AS tid2 
FROM forum_topics WHERE `category_id` ='".$cid."' AS t JOIN forum_posts AS p on t.id = p.topic_id 
GROUP BY t.id DESC")`

Comment: Ok i got this.. Just put [WHERE t.category_id = ".$cid)] and make sure you dont add any extra elements... Like commas etci

Comment: I just tried this... GROUP BY t.id DESC [WHERE t.category_id = ".$cid);]")

Comment: Oh no you again put it worng way... Wait let me update the full query in my answer...

Comment: I put it at the end of the query.

Comment: It just shows my error message... Query2 failed: %s

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly other than all of the topics would show up no matter which category I was in.

Comment: Well i updated the query again in answer see now if it still doesn't work try replacing ".$cid."  with 1 or 2

Comment: Happy to help becky..!! :),  the only problem was the small space before GROUP BY t.id DESC...